# Running an FQL query using Facebook's Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

This is my query:

```
select uid, name, is_app_user from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me()) and is_app_user=1
```

and I need to run it using the Javascript SDK. How do I do this? I'm not sure about the syntax and formatting. The above FQL query works when I run it in the Open Graph Explorer (FBL section) but I can't manage to get it to work in the Graph API section.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this via the FB.api() method of the JS SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api) by using the

```
/fql?q=
```

endpoint if you URL encode your query like this

```
/fql?q=select%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20is_app_user%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20(select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%3Dme())%20and%20is_app_user%3D1&access_token={YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

JS code would look like this for example:

```
FB.api('/fql?q=select%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20is_app_user%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20in%20(select%20uid2%20from%20friend%20where%20uid1%3Dme())%20and%20is_app_user%3D1&access_token={YOUR_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Don't forget to add your Access Token!

Comment: Great, thanks! How does that encoding work? Is there a JS function that I can use to encode my queries?

Answer (score 1):

Execute query via `FB.api`-

```
FB.api("/fql?q="+encodeURIComponent('{your-query}'), function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
     console.log('Error occurred: '+response.error.message);
  } else {
     console.log(response);
  }
});
```